# C# Windows Application Timer Stops

Tags: c#, windows, timer

I have an Windows Application which uses timer like in the screen: 
timer it's used to run a method every X minutes between 08:00:00 (Start Time) and 21:00:00 (Stop Time) 
In the screen:
Next download Start at: shows what time the next run will occur
Time Left: shows the remaining time until next run will occur
Download Interval: time span between two runs

The method runs when the Next download Start = Current Time.

My issue is that event that the application is open and runs, the timer just stops after a while. 
Any ideas why this happens, is this normal or am I doing something wrong in my code (i can post it if needed but now I was just asking to see if it's normal)?
Is there a way to prevent it or shell I create a checker and check his status regularly?

Thanks in advance for your support!

[image: Main screen with the timers]

```
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timerFrequency = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    public void LoadGeneraInfoPanel()
   {
            timerFrequency.Interval = 1000;
            timerFrequency.Enabled = true;
            this.timerFrequency.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timerFrequency_Tick);
            timerFrequency.Start();

        }

  private void timerFrequency_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtGICurrTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

            if (drSystemParam["Auto"].ToString() == "True" && timerFrequency.Enabled)
            {
                if (txtGIFrequency.Text.ToString() != string.Empty && txtGIStopTime.Text.ToString() != string.Empty && txtGIStartTime.Text.ToString() != string.Empty)
                {
                    int iHours = Convert.ToInt32(txtGIFrequency.Text.Substring(0, 2));
                    int iMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(txtGIFrequency.Text.Substring(3, 2));
                    int iSeconds = Convert.ToInt32(txtGIFrequency.Text.Substring(6, 2));

                    DateTime dCurrStartTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, Convert.ToInt32(txtGIStartTime.Text.Substring(0, 2)), Convert.ToInt32(txtGIStartTime.Text.Substring(3, 2)), Convert.ToInt32(txtGIStartTime.Text.Substring(6, 2)));
                    DateTime dCurrStopTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, Convert.ToInt32(txtGIStopTime.Text.Substring(0, 2)), Convert.ToInt32(txtGIStopTime.Text.Substring(3, 2)), Convert.ToInt32(txtGIStopTime.Text.Substring(6, 2)));


                    DateTime dCurrStartDownloadTime = dCurrStartTime;

                    for (int j = 0; dCurrStartDownloadTime < DateTime.Now & dCurrStartDownloadTime <= dCurrStopTime; j++)
                        dCurrStartDownloadTime = dCurrStartDownloadTime.AddHours(iHours).AddMinutes(iMinutes).AddSeconds(iSeconds);

                    var result = dCurrStartDownloadTime;

                    if (DateTime.Now > dCurrStartTime && DateTime.Now < dCurrStopTime.AddHours(-iHours).AddMinutes(-iMinutes).AddSeconds(-iSeconds))
                    {
                        if (txtNextDownloadTime.Text == String.Empty)
                            txtNextDownloadTime.Text = result.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

                        TimeSpan diff = result - DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1);
                        txtGITimeLeft.Text = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", diff.Hours.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), diff.Minutes.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), diff.Seconds.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));

                        if (DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") == txtNextDownloadTime.Text)
                        {
                            timerFrequency.Stop();
                            txtNextDownloadTime.Text = result.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                            Thread.Sleep(800);

                            timerFrequency.Enabled = true;
                            timerFrequency.Start();

                            btnEecuteMethod_Click(sender, e);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        result = dCurrStartTime.AddDays(1);
                        txtNextDownloadTime.Text = result.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                        TimeSpan diff = result - DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1);
                        txtGITimeLeft.Text = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", diff.Hours.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), diff.Minutes.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), diff.Seconds.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    timerFrequency.Enabled = false;
                    timerFrequency.Stop();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: what does your code look like? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Post some codes so we can determine what you have tried..

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Please read that link and let us know if you have any concerns in creating one.

Comment: Your EventHandler is doing _way_ too much. I'd break this up into smaller pieces. Also, the parsing seems superfluent to me. Keep DateTimes in a model object. I am confident you'll find the issue if you do that.

Comment: @A.S. - Thank you for providing the code. You have a lot of code there that is parsing and converting to strings - it's a bit tricky to tease out the logic from the data. It's really hard to give you concrete advice with such code, but there is one line that sticks out to me as a possible candidate for your troubles. The line `if (DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") == txtNextDownloadTime.Text)` appears to me that this line could easily be skipped if the tick doesn't fire within the exact second you're looking for. Can you test if this is the cause of your issue?

Comment: @Enigmativity - I am using this timer in a control and it's used many times and for some controls it stops and i am having this issue, I will create a new one and set the interval accordingly and try it like this, thanks a lot for you suggestion

Comment: @Enigmativity So I am using user controls because i have multiple branches and I think the issue is with the timer form windows.forms which is not working fine on multithreading. On the other hand I've tried to use a Threading.Timer or Timers.Timer but the thing is that the UI is not updated, the text controls. So I was kind of stuck here and now I am trying some workaround with the Windows.Forms.Timer to update the UI and a kind of "checker" which is a Timers.Timer to check if the Windows.Forms.Timer is enabled. Now it's running but not sure if it's fine,do you think it's ok like this?

Comment: @A.S. - You'd have to show me the final code to say if it is ok or not. Just one thing - if you use a thread other than the UI thread then you must call `control.Invoke` to marshall the call back to the UI thread. This includes interacting with any `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` from another thread.